# Missing Registry keys: HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\Microsoft\Office

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry, windows-11

I have a bit of a pickle: One of my clients does not have an Office Directory in their Registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\Microsoft\Office). We use M365 and the Office Suite was installed through a bog standard Setup.exe.
I wanted to change a Registry Key for Outlook, yet I cannot find the mentioned directory anywhere. It does exists on 2 other clients.

Does anyone have an idea what happened here? Is there a different directory these keys could have been saved? AFAIK this is the default directory for Office Programs. I have been looking through the Directories manually and with the Search function but nothing comes up. It's not a MS Store App either.

Update: Tried reinstalling while typing this out, nothing changed.

tl;dr

- OS Win11
- Using M365 Suite
- HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\Microsoft\Office missing
- Directory present on 2 other clients
- how??

Comment: Uninstall Office, restart, install it again and patch it. Test.

Comment: Tried reinstalling, same issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to rebuild the machine

Comment: Export the registry key from a system where it does exist and import it on the systems where it doesn't exist.

Comment: *"I wanted to change a Registry Key for Outlook"*. Can you be more specific what you tried to change, which specific key/value? Did you do a Find on the whole Registry for that key/value?

Comment: See https://office365itpros.com/2018/10/15/office-clicktorun-registry/ for other Registry locations.

Comment: 32-bit office could use `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office` instead. Are you accessing the registry remotely or as a different user account?

Comment: I also think that the difference between the computers is that the other two have installed 64-bit Office, while this one has installed the 32-bit version of Office.

Comment: If there are other clients with same issue, I would suggest you check your windows system or windows user account.